# My Directional light lights the floor of my cave but not the ceiling (concave mesh)

Tags: lighting, three.js

I am developing a small demo with Meshes created from a vertex map.

When i put a hole in the mesh (making it concave) the physics work fine but the directional lightning only lights one part of the concave park.

All of my mesh can receive and and cast shadow (so i should have self-shadowing) but it does not seem to work.

my directional light creation:

```js
            var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
            dirLight.position.set( -50, 50, 1 );
            dirLight.position.multiplyScalar( 50);
            dirLight.name = "dirlight";
   dirLight.castShadow = true;
            dirLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
   dirLight.shadowDarkness = 1.0;
```

my shadow settings:

```js
   renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth/1, window.innerHeight/1 );
   renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
   renderer.shadowMapSoft = true;

   renderer.shadowCameraNear = 3;
   renderer.shadowCameraFar = camera.far;
   renderer.shadowCameraFov = 50;

   renderer.shadowMapBias = 0.0039;
   renderer.shadowMapDarkness = 0.5;
   renderer.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
   renderer.shadowMapHeight = 1024;
```

Finally my mesh creation code:

```js
var newGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
for (var i = 0; i < rawGeometry.vertices.length; i++) {
  newGeometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(rawGeometry.vertices[i][0], rawGeometry.vertices[i][1], rawGeometry.vertices[i][2]))
}
for (var i = 0; i < rawGeometry.faces.length; i++) {
  newGeometry.faces.push(new THREE.Face3(rawGeometry.faces[i][0], rawGeometry.faces[i][1], rawGeometry.faces[i][2]))
}

newGeometry.computeFaceNormals();
;

var color = rawGeometry.color;
var newMesh = new Physijs.ConcaveMesh(newGeometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
  color: color
}), 0, 50, 50);
newMesh.position.x = location[0];
newMesh.position.y = location[1];
newMesh.position.z = location[2];

newMesh.castShadow = true;
newMesh.receiveShadow = true;

this.Chunks[chunkIndex[0]][chunkIndex[1]][chunkIndex[2]][typeIndex] = newMesh;

scene.add(newMesh);
```

[image: floor is lite, but not the ceiling]

[image: However this shadows from a mesh on another displays fine]